# Subtle oop differences between java and php

Tags: java, php, oop

I found this case

** php example **

```
abstract class class1{  
    function test(){}  
}


abstract class class2 extends class1{  
    abstract function test();  
}
```

This oop concept works in Java, in PHP it doesn't.(`Cannot make non abstract method class1::test() abstract in class class2`)

What other subtle differences there are between Java and PHP oop ?

Comment: void ... in java.. but the same oop principle

Comment: If this is a compilation of such differences, you should make this community wiki, as there is no final answer to your "question".

Comment: I don't think there is a sense in discussing questions like "what is the difference between pinetree and firtree". They are just different.

Comment: @FractalizeR: I'd say if a user is learning PHP and comes from a Java background (or vice versa), then there's definitely a sense to it - it's a compilation of gotchas. "This doesn't work quite the same way here."

Comment: To bad nobody is adding examples.

Comment: Do you want subtle examples, or straight "punch in the face-different" examples?

Answer (score 16):

Java and PHP (even when using OO PHP) have a vast array of differences.

Just a few thoughts off the top of my head:

1. Java is strongly-typed, PHP is not, although there is a limited scope for type-hinting in PHP.  This makes a huge difference to method signatures.  In PHP, you can only force method parameters to be of a certain class or interface or an array:

`public function myMethod(SomeClass $foo, array $bar){}`

...but you cannot type-hint for primitives! So `public function myMethod(int $foo, boolean $bar){}` is invalid and will throw a parse error.

Furthermore, any parameter that has been type-hinted cannot be passed as `null` *unless `null` is given as a default value*.  So to allow `null`s, you need to use:

`public function myMethod(SomeClass $foo = null)`

2. PHP does not require (or even support) specifying the return type of a function.
3. PHP classes do not have `final` fields, although what would be a `static final` field in Java is a `const` in PHP. EDIT: A `const` in PHP is more limited than a `static final` in Java as the latter can be an array or object instance, whereas the former must be a constant value (number or a string, essentially).
4. "Overloading" in PHP does not mean the same as it does in Java.  In Java, it means specifying multiple methods of the same name, but with a different set of parameters:

`public void myMethod(int foo){};  public void myMethod(float foo){};`

In PHP, it refers to the dynamic creation of properties and methods using the `__get()`, `__set()` and `__callStatic()` "magic" methods.  See the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php) for a description on their use.  Java-style method overloading is impossible in PHP and an attempt to redeclare a method (with or without a different set of parameters) will fail.

5. May be obvious to some, but in PHP you use `::` to access static methods and properties and `->` to access instance ones, but in Java `.` is used for both.
6. PHP doesn't have packages, but it does have *namespaces*.
7. As of PHP5, constructors in PHP are not supposed to be methods with a name that matches the class, like in Java, but the magic method `__construct()` should be declared instead, although the PHP4 style is supported for backward-compatibility.  Also, PHP has a destructor method named `__destruct()`.
8. In Java, all classes inherit from `Object`, but there is no such generic super-class in PHP.
9. Even when maximizing the amount of OOP in a PHP script, it still relies on a procedural flow; there's no class-level entry point like in Java (i.e., `public static void main(String[] args)` or `public void init()` for applets).

Comment: `const` and `final` are semantically different anyway.

Comment: Yes they are.  My point is that the closest you can get to Java's `static final` in PHP is a `const` and that PHP has no property-level `final` equivalence.

Comment: points 1 and 2 are not relevant after php 7 release.